# displaying a baseline h264 frames stream in browsers

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, webrtc, video-streaming, h.264

So, I have a server that receives a live rtsp stream then generates baseline h264 frames using ffmpeg, which then are sent via an rtcDataChannel to browser, and while the frames arrive as intended, I can't figure out a way to display them on my html5 videoElement,
here is a simplified version of my current approach:

```
const remoteStream = new MediaSource();
myVideoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(remoteStream);

// called when remoteStream.readyState === "open"
let sourceBuffer = remoteStream.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d002a"');

// this gets called when ever a new frame is received from the webrtc data channel.
function onFrame(frame) {
      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(frame));

      /*
      console.log(frame) ==> <Buffer 00 00 00 01 41 9b a0 22 80 a5 d7 a0 42 ea 34 14 
        85 ba bc 1b f2 71 22 0d 8b e1 3c 52 d5 e1 80 8b 9b 8c ef c1 c1 89 3c 10 c5 05 
        78 a0 41 ee 3c 1d 03 8d ... 2896 more bytes>
      */
}
```

ffmpeg options:

```
[
    "-rtsp_transport", "tcp",
    "-i", `${rtspCamURL}`,  
    "-framerate", "15",
    "-c:v", "libx264",
    "-vprofile", "baseline",
    "-b:v", "600k",
    "-bufsize", "600k",
    "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
    '-tune', 'zerolatency',
    "-preset", "ultrafast",
    "-f", "rawvideo",
    '-'
];
```

ffmpeg stream is then split using NAL delimiter (to generate individual frames) then each frame is sent via the data channel like so :
`Buffer.concat([nalDelimiter, frame])`.

I am not sure if i'm missing something as i'm not getting any helpful errors due to the remoteSource closing as soon as the first frame arrives for some reason.

or does the media source just not support raw h264 frames, and if so is there a workaround to solve this issue? (even if it has to do with changing the ffmpeg params.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into doing something like [RTSPtoWebRTC](https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWebRTC). Sending them over the RTCDataChannel may work, but isn't going to be as portable.

If you want to continue using RTCDataChannel you need to update your ffmpeg command to emit a mp4. If you are re-encoding and have the flexibility it might even be worth exploring other options (VP8/webm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not sure by what you mean by portable, I just checked out the library, but I've never really used go before, so I couldn't figure out how he is generating a media stream from the rtsp feed, which is the reason I'm using data channels in the first place, and I can't use a fully prebuilt project as the service needs to support a lot more functionality.
 
Do you mind expanding on the mp4 way, should I just change the ffmpeg config, or would I need to change the way the client handles the data as well?

Comment: As for the VP8 encoding I can't go that route as server running the service can't handle it